# Convert JSON array to Objective-C in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

I am new to iOS development. I am trying to covert JSOn array values to Objective-C values. My JSON values are like this:

```
{"result":
        [{"alternative":
                    [{"transcript":"4"},
                    {"transcript":"four"},
                    {"transcript":"so"},
                    {"transcript":"who"}],
    "final":true}],
 "result_index":0}
```

I have tried it this way:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:speechrequestString]];

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *speechResult= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray *speechArray= [speechResult valueForKey:@"result"];
NSLog(@"%@",speechArray);

NSLog(@"Response is of type: %@", [speechArray class]);
```

`speechArray` is always null. How to resolvee this problem?
At the same time I would like to print `transcript` values.

Comment: speechArray value always print null. thanks@Avi

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in initializing the array and Dictionary.

Try doing this,

```
NSDictionary *speechResult = [NSDictionary new];

NSArray *speechArray = [NSArray new];
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the array before using it,

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:speechrequestString]];

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *speechResult= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray *speechArray= [[NSArray alloc] init];
speechArray= [speechResult valueForKey:@"result"];
if (speechArray.count>0) {
  NSDictionary * alternativeDictn = [speechArray objectAtIndex:0];
  NSArray *alternativeAry= [[NSArray alloc] init];
  alternativeAry = [alternativeDictn objectForKey:@"alternative"];
  NSLog(@"%@",alternativeAry);
}

NSLog(@"Response is of type: %@", [speechArray class]);
```

Using this code you will get following result,

```
(
        {
        transcript = 4;
    },
        {
        transcript = four;
    },
        {
        transcript = so;
    },
        {
        transcript = who;
    }
)
```

Comment: i would like to print  transcript values. [{"transcript":"4"},
                    {"transcript":"four"},
                    {"transcript":"so"},
                    {"transcript":"who"}],

Comment: @amsaraj Check my updated answer, i have changed it according to your need

Comment: @amsaraj let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: 2016-05-05 13:24:36.396 SpeechToTextDemo[18148:2489059] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @amsaraj - can you give your request URL , I give the answwre

Comment: 2016-05-05 13:30:59.815 SpeechToTextDemo[18973:2497824] responseString: {"result":[]}
{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"one"},{"transcript":"1"}],"final":true}],"result_index":0}

Comment: i am using google speech api.. i am try to implement speech to text in ios

Comment: NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseString: %@",responseString);

Comment: still i have this problem please guide me thanks @anbu @ dilip

Comment: @amsaraj, i was not aware that you are getting empty result, Check my code now, i have updated it so if its empty than it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

try this may be it will help you:-

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:speechrequestString]];

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *speechResult = [NSDictionary new];
speechResult= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray *speechArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
speechArray= [speechResult valueForKey:@"result"];
NSLog(@"%@",speechArray);

NSLog(@"Response is of type: %@", [speechArray class]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];//data is your response from server as NSData

if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){ //Added instrospection as suggested in comment.
    NSArray * speechArray = json[@"result"];
}

NSLog(@"speech array %@",speechArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the value in NSDictionary (speechResult).

If it is nil, check the json data isValid or not.

```
   NSError *error;
    if ([NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                        options:kNilOptions
                                          error:&error] == nil)
    {
        // Check the error here
    }else {
        // here check whether it is a dictionary and it has key like @Bhadresh Mulsaniya mentioned.
    }
```

If returns nil, then you check the error to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
restaurantdictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mutableData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

NSMutableArray *main_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

main_array=[restaurantdictionary valueForKey:@"results"];

NSLog(@"main_array %@", main_array);
```

its working for me, hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code to get the transcripts:

```
    NSData* jsonData = [yourJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *responseObj = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                 options:0
                                 error:&error];

    if(! error) {
        NSArray *responseArray = [responseObj objectForKey:@"result"];
        for (NSDictionary *alternative in responseArray) {
            NSArray *altArray = [alternative objectForKey:@"alternative"];
            for (NSDictionary *transcript in altArray) {
                NSLog(@"transcript : %@",[transcript objectForKey:@"transcript"]);
            }
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error in parsing JSON");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should alloc your dictionary first like this-

```
   NSDictionary *speechResult = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
    speechResult= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *speechArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    speechArray= [speechResult valueForKey:@"result"];
```